# Using the sendgrid node-module, how do I send a SendGrid Template Engine email?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I have created a "Thanks for subscribing" email template via SendGrid's Template Engine.

Now, when someone subscribes to my site, I want to send that person that template. Can I do this using the [sendgrid-nodejs](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs) package?

I don't see anything regarding this in the docs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep, it's really easy, you just need to add it in as a filter. Here's how it should look:

```
var cardEmail = new sendgrid.Email({
  to: "theuser@somedomain.com",
  from: "bignews@yourdomain.com",
  subject: process.env.SUBJECT,
  html: '<h2>Thanks for requesting a business card!</h2>', // This fills out the <%body%> tag inside your SendGrid template
});

// Tell SendGrid which template to use, and what to substitute. You can use as many substitutions as you want.
cardEmail.setFilters({"templates": {"settings": {"enabled": 1, "template_id": "325ae5e7-69dd-4b95-b003-b0109f750cfa"}}}); // Just replace this with the ID of the template you want to use
cardEmail.addSubstitution('-greeting-', "Happy Friday!"); // You don't need to have a substitution, but if you want it, here's how you do that :)

// Everything is set up, let's send the email!
sendgrid.send(cardEmail, function(err, json){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent!');
  }
});
```

I hope that helps you out. If you need more insight into it, please check out the blog post I wrote about [using Template Engine with sendgrid-nodejs](https://sendgrid.com/blog/migrating-app-sendgrids-template-engine/).

Comment: What is a subsitution? like tags with Mandrill? :)

Answer (score 4):

To make it work with version 4.x.x use this:

```js
var helper = require('sendgrid').mail;
var from_email = new helper.Email('test@example.com');
var to_email = new helper.Email('test@example.com');
var subject = 'I\'m replacing the subject tag';
var content = new helper.Content('text/html', 'I\'m replacing the <strong>body tag</strong>');
var mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);
mail.personalizations[0].addSubstitution(new helper.Substitution('-name-', 'Example User'));
mail.personalizations[0].addSubstitution(new helper.Substitution('-city-', 'Denver'));
mail.setTemplateId('13b8f94f-bcae-4ec6-b752-70d6cb59f932');
```

[Full example](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#transactional_templates)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the SMTPAPI's app(filters) methods for sending of templates. I don't believe it's yet supported by the web API. Here's some docs:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/apps.html#templates

Comment: Calling the template can only be done in the x-smtpapi argument, but that argument can be made in a [webapi call](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html#-send)